# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

```
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config

class app(App):
    Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
    Config.set('graphics', 'width', 375)
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', 750)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.parent = Widget()
        im = CoreImage("1.png")
        self.parent.add_widget(Button(im))
        return self.parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app().run()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 500)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 300)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):   
        grid_layout = GridLayout(cols = 5, spacing = 20, padding = 30)
        grid_layout.add_widget(Button(background_normal=('image.jpg'), on_press = self.hello))
        return grid_layout

    def hello(self, instance):
        print("Нажата кнопка")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```